# Не работает VPN через Xray XTLS-Reality на Mac M1

Tags: macos, vpn, xray

Настроил Xray сервер, устанавливаю конфигурацию клиента, на iPhone и Windows все работает нормально, но на MacBook M1 ничего не отрывается. В браузере появляется ошибка ERR_TUNNEL_CONNECTION_FAILED.

Конфигурации клиента везде одинаковые.

На Windows использую Necoray, на iPhone - Shadowrocket, на Mac пробовал Shadowrocket и FoxRay.

Ранее на маке все работало, но сейчас нет. Установлена Sonoma 14.2.1

Кто сталкивался или в курсе как почитить?

Comment: Удалось что-то выяснить? Столкнулся с тем же самым. Сидел на outline все было без проблем. С xray (клиент FoxRay) на маке постоянные ошибки и долгие загрузки

Comment: @Gleb к сожалению, пока ничего. Сейчас необходимости нет, так как нахожусь в регионе, где работает OpenVPN. Но если понадобится, хочу сделать сброс до заводских настроек на Маке.

Answer (score 0):

Сталкивался с подобным у Hiddify. Возможно в конфигурации какая-то ошибка, при этом установлено автоматическое подключение при загрузке. Использую FoxRay и Straisand, проблем нет.